# FTP connection performance java

Tags: java, ftp

I Want to optimize performance by opening FTP connection once.Can it be possible ?

I am doing as ,

```
public void method1()
{
  for(loop)
  {
    List li = someList;
    method2(li); //Here I am calling this method in loop. This method has code for FTP connection. So for every iteration it is opening FTP connection in method2().
  }
}

public void method2(List li)
{
 open FTP connection // FTP connect code here
 once FTP connection obtained ....do some other stuff...
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static (or indeed instance) variable that is created once like so;

```
private static FTPConnection myFTPCon = openFTPConnection();

private static FTPConnection openFTPConnection()
{
    //open ftp connection here and return it
}

public void method1()
{
    for(loop)
    {
        List li = someList;
        method2(li);
    }
}

public synchronized void method2(List li)
{
     //use myFTPCon here
}
```

---

**Edit in response to comment**

```
public class MyFTPClass {

    private FTPConnection myFTPCon;

    public MyFTPClass(String host, String user, String password) {
        //connect to the ftp server and assign a value to myFTPCon
    }

    public synchronized void method() {
        //use the myFTPCon object here
    }
}
```

You would then construct a `MyFTPClass` object from your main program flow, and use it from there. Each new `MyFTPClass` instance refers to a different FTP server connection, so you can have as many as you need.

Comment: Thanks lynks. But while connecting to FTP location I have to provide some file name which will be stored at FTP location  like URL url = new URL("ftp://" + userName + ":" + password + "@"+ hostName + "/" + fileName + ";type=i");  // Here fileName. which is dynamic in my case every time. So how I can obtain that dynamic value in myFTPCon variable in method2?

Comment: see my edit, the new code can sit in its own source file MyFTPClass.java, and you can run your program alongside it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't explain us what optimization you want to do.
Do you want to reuse a connection ? it's not possible to use a connection in a multi-threaded way (imagine sending in a stream commands while a file is transferring : it's not possible).

The only optimization is to keep the connection opened between 2 sets of commands (you avoid the cost of closing and reopening the connection, which is quite costly).

Be very careful with the static stuff : problems usually happen when going in a multithreaded environment (for example an application server).